# Can anyone correct my prolog answer for the given statement if it is wrong?

Tags: prolog

1.Whale has a backbone.

```
whale(X):-backbone(X).
```

2.Whale grows with their mother's milk.

```
whale(X):-grows(X,Y),milk(Y,mother).
```

OR

```
grows(X):-whale(X),drinks(X,mother's_milk).
```

Answer (score 3):

It really depends how you want to organize your database. You could, for example, also say:

> A vertebrate (has a backbone) is a whale, or a dog, or a snake.

```
vertebrate(whale).
vertebrate(god).
vertebrate(snake).
```

> Is whale a vertebrate?

```
?- vertebrate(whale).
true.
```

Similarly,

> A mammal (feeds on their mother's milk) is a whale, or a dog.

```
mammal(whale).
mammal(dog).
```

The message here is that since you need to actully provide the database in some form, and since "has spine" and "is vertebrate" are the same thing, you might as well explicitly list all mammals.

Or are you thinking of some use case where the argument to `whale/1` is an object created by the program, and backbone needs to look at it in some specific way (look at the value of an attribute, for example) to succeed or fail?

### Edit

Think about it like this:

> Whale has a backbone

```
has(whale, backbone).
```

But then, you could write,

```
vertebrate(X) :-
    has_backbone(X).

has_backbone(X) :-
    has(X, backbone).
```

And at that point you should see why this is indeed not necessary. Just write:

```
vertebrate(whale). % :- has_backbone(whalte) :- has(whale, backbone).
```

And, in the same way:

> Whale grows on their mother's milk

```
grows_on(whale, 'mother\'s milk').

has(X, 'mammary glands') :-
    grows_on(X, 'mother\'s milk').

mammal(X) :-
    has(X, 'mammary glands').
```

Identical to above, you end up with:

```
mammal(whale).
```

Comment: can you please explain further...?? So don't we need to use rules in here and show them?? So you said that both are same.. mammal(whale).
 and backbone(whale). Also second one then must be feeds_on_their_mothers_milk(whale).  Is it correct then??

Comment: @thsumia The point is that a "mammals" do feed on their mother's milk. So you might as well just say `mammal(whale).`

Comment: So can you tell me what is the final answer should be?? to write above whole code in prolog?? please.

Comment: first one is ok for me..but second one still have the problem.

Comment: An eloquent description... I think you meant `vertebrate(god)` @Boris

Answer (score 2):

As Boris indicates, it depends upon how you want to organize your data. Specifically, upon what detailed level you want to define your facts. If you get down to lower level facts, you'd look at the definition for *mammal*, for instance ([OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/mammal)):

> **Mammal:** a warm-blooded vertebrate animal of a class that is
>   distinguished by the possession of hair or fur, the secretion of milk
>   by females for the nourishment of the young, and (typically) the birth
>   of live young.

So here, assuming the conditions given in the above definition are not only necessary but sufficient, you could define *mammal* in detail as:

```
mammal(X) :-
    vertebrate(X),
    warm_blooded(X),
    (has_fur(X) ; has_hair(X)),
    feeds_by_milk(X),
    gives_live_birth(X).
```

Which would then require that you define all of these kinds facts for whatever beasts/things you are wanting to query about. (And, yes, a whale has hair, although very little of it.) The statement:

*Whale grows with their mother's milk.*

Would be a fact, not based upon a rule, because there's no fundamental fact that such a rule would be derived from. The fact, using the terms I introduced above, would be:

```
feeds_by_milk(whale).
```

If you don't want to have all those detailed data, then you'd do as Boris showed which is establish your lowest level facts as *mammal*:

```
mammal(whale).
mammal(dog).
```

In Prolog, it's important to think carefully about how facts are defined and what they really mean, semantically. In your initial example, you have what appears to be a fact called `milk` that has two arguments. You have an example usage, `milk(Y, mother)`, but it doesn't very directly express the fact that `Y` feeds on it's mother's milk. It introduces `mother` as an argument, but unnecessarily since it's not likely that you'd have also something like `milk(Y, father)`. `feeds_by_milk(Y)` or even, `feeds_on_mothers_milk(Y)` is a better expression of the fact in this case. Likewise, `whale(X)` doesn't have clear semantics. What is `X` in this case? Do the whales have personal names, like `whale(shamu)`? Perhaps. The above discussion is dealing with whales categorically. That is, a whale, in this discussion, is an atomic entity, so would more likely be the argument in your facts, not one of the fact names. If you want to deal with them individually (*e.g.*, answer the question, *Is Shamu a whale?*) then you would need a rule that identifies `whale(X)` using facts and rules which eventually lead to questions to the user such as, *Is shamu warm blooded?*, and then after answers to such questions are asserted, the query `whale(shamu)` run to see if it succeeds.

Comment: Please note the difference between the OED definition and your first Prolog rule. The OED definition only says **a** warm-blooded etc.etc. But your Prolog rule reads: **Every** vertebrate that is warm blooded etc.etc. is a mammal.

Comment: @false yes good catch. Technically, the definition does read as you say (stated as a necessary but not sufficient condition), but for the sake of this discussion, I think it's adequate to consider the conditions sufficient. Any other conditions that are required could be researched and added to the rule.

Comment: both sentences are separate ones. I only want to write "Whale grows with their mother's milk" in prolog form. That is why I was in a trouble. So thank you every one who helped me.

Comment: @thsumia in that case, in the terms I posed in my answer, that would be, `feeds_by_milk(whale).` It would be  basic fact, not a derived fact via a rule.

Comment: @thsumia if I answered your question, perhaps you could click the accept. Or let me know if anything needs further clarification. Thanks. :)

Comment: @Iurker I have more questions to ask further..This is enough for now.

Comment: @thsumia if you have new questions, those should be for a new post